# Pre-process text string with NLTK

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have a dataframe A containing docid(document ID), title(title of the article), lineid(line ID, aka the location of the paragraph), text, and tokencount(counts of words including white spaces):

```
  docid   title  lineid                                         text        tokencount
0     0     A        0   shopping and orders have become more com...                66
1     0     A        1  people wrote to the postal service online...                67
2     0     A        2   text updates really from the U.S. Postal...                43
...
```

I want to create a new dataframe based on A including `title`, `lineid`, `count`, and `query`.

`query` is the text string containing one or more words like "data analysis", "text message", or "shopping and orders".

`count` is the counts of each word of the `query`.

The new dataframe should look like this:

```
title  lemma   count   lineid
  A    "data"    0        0
  A    "data"    1        1
  A    "data"    4        2
  A    "shop"    2        0
  A    "shop"    1        1
  A    "shop"    2        2
  B    "data"    4        0
  B    "data"    0        1
  B    "data"    2        2
  B    "shop"    9        0
  B    "shop"    3        1
  B    "shop"    1        2
...
```

How to make a function to generate this new dataframe?

---

I have created a new dataframe `df` from A with a column `count`.

```
df = A[['title','lineid']]
df['count'] = 0
df.set_index(['title','lineid'], inplace=True)
```

Also, I have created a function to count word of query.

```
from collections import Counter

def occurrence_counter(target_string, query):
    data = dict(Counter(target_string.split()))
    count = 0
    for key in query:
        if key in data:
            count += data[key]
    return count
```

But, how can I use both of them to generate a function of a new dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with built-in pandas functions: [**`Series.str.count()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to count the `queries`; [**`melt()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to reshape into the final column structure.

Given the sample `df`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'docid': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0}, 'title': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'A'}, 'lineid': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2}, 'text': {0: 'shopping and orders have become more com...',  1: 'people wrote to the postal service online...',  2: 'text updates really from the U.S. Postal...'}, 'tokencount': {0: 66, 1: 67, 2: 43}})

#   docid  title  lineid                                          text
# 0     0      A       0   shopping and orders have become more com...
# 1     0      A       1  people wrote to the postal service online...
# 2     0      A       2   text updates really from the U.S. Postal...
```

First [**`count()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) the `queries`:

```py
queries = ['order', 'shop', 'text']
df = df.assign(**{f'query_{query}': df.text.str.count(query) for query in queries})

#   docid  title  lineid                                          text  tokencount  query_order  query_shop  query_text
# 0     0      A       0   shopping and orders have become more com...          66            1           1           0
# 1     0      A       1  people wrote to the postal service online...          67            0           0           0
# 2     0      A       2   text updates really from the U.S. Postal...          43            0           0           1
```

Then [**`melt()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) into the final column structure:

```py
df.melt(
    id_vars=['title', 'lineid'],
    value_vars=[f'query_{query}' for query in queries],
    var_name='lemma',
    value_name='count',
).replace(r'^query_', '', regex=True)

#   title  lineid  lemma  count
# 0     A       0  order      1
# 1     A       1  order      0
# 2     A       2  order      0
# 3     A       0   shop      1
# 4     A       1   shop      0
# 5     A       2   shop      0
# 6     A       0   text      0
# 7     A       1   text      0
# 8     A       2   text      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should handle your scenario:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

query = "data analysis"
wordlist = query.split(" ")
#print(wordlist)

# row wise frequency count
df['text_new']  = df.text.str.split().apply(lambda x: Counter(x))

output = pd.DataFrame()
# iterate row by row
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    temp = dict()
    for word in wordlist:
        temp['title']  = row['title']
        temp['lemma']  = word
        temp['count']  = row['text_new'][word]
        temp['lineid'] = row['lineid']
    
    output = output.append(temp, ignore_index=True)
#print(output)
```